# Computing SSREG and SSRES (Regression)

Tags: regression

SSREG is calculated with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\hat Y_i - \bar{Y})^2$ which is the regression sum of squares

SSRES is calculated with $\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( Y_i - \hat Y_i)^2$ which is the residual sum of squares

If we are given

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = 323.02, \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i = 333.15, \sum_{i=1}
^{n} X_i^2 = 1021.487, \hat\beta_0 = 1.097, \hat\beta_1 = 0.674 $$

I cant seem to find relevant formulas to help me compute it with given info the best I found was

$SSREG = \hat\beta^2_{1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \bar{X})^2 $

[image]

Is there an easier one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be given the sample size $n$, then 
For the SSReg you are right, you have all its components, just plug it in the formula
$$
SSreg = \hat{\beta}_1^2(\sum X_i^2 -n \bar{X}_n^2)=0.0674^2(1021.487 -  323.02^2/n )
$$ 
and 
$$
SSres=SST-SSreg = \sum Y_i^2-n \bar{Y}_n^2-SSreg
$$
where for the SST you need $\bar{Y}_n$ that you can derive from 
$$
\hat{\beta}_0=\bar{Y}_n-\bar{X}_n\hat{\beta}_1.
$$

Comment: Many thanks! Quick question though: $SSreg = \hat{\beta}_1^2(\sum X_i^2 -n \bar{X}_n^2)=0.0674^2(1021.487 -  323.02^2/n )$ for this you put $n \bar{X}^2$ but did $323.02^2 / n$ in the equation. So is it $SSreg = \hat{\beta}_1^2(\sum X_i^2 - \bar{X}_n^2 / n)=0.0674^2(1021.487 -  323.02^2/n )$

Comment: $\sum X_i = n\bar{X}_n$, $(\sum X_i ) ^2 = n^2\bar{X}_n^2$

Comment: So $\bar{X_n}^2 = 323.02^2$ right? Then how is $n \bar{X_n}^2 = 323.02^2/n$ ?

Comment: $ (\sum X_i )^2/n =n^2 \bar{X}_n^2/n = n \bar{X}_n^2 $